# Rails ActiveAdmin: showing table of a related resource in the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When `show`ing a resource using the Rails ActiveAdmin gem, I want to show a table of another associated model.

So let's say a `Winery` `has_many` `:products`. Now I want to show the products associated on the `show` page of the `Winery` admin resource. And I want that to be a table similar to what I would get on the `index` of the `Products` resource.

I got it to work, but only by recreating the HTML structure manually, which kind of sucks.  Is there a cleaner way to create an `index` table style view for a specific subset of an associated resource?

What I have, which kinda sucks:

```
show title: :name do |winery|
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    row(:region) { |o| o.region.name }
    rows :primary_contact, :description
  end

  # This is the part that sucks.
  div class: 'panel' do
    h3 'Products'
    div class: 'attributes_table' do
      table do
        tr do
          th 'Name'
          th 'Vintage'
          th 'Varietal'
        end
        winery.products.each do |product|
          tr do
            td link_to product.name, admin_product_path(product)
            td product.vintage
            td product.varietal.name
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To solve this problem, we used partials:

`/app/admin/wineries.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Winery do
  show title: :name do
    render "show", context: self
  end
end
```

`app/admin/products.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  belongs_to :winery
  index do
    render "index", context: self
  end
end
```

`/app/views/admin/wineries/_show.builder`

```
context.instance_eval  do
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    row :region
    row :primary_contact
  end
  render "admin/products/index", products: winery.products, context: self
  active_admin_comments
end
```

`/app/views/admin/products/_index.builder`

```
context.instance_eval  do
  table_for(invoices, :sortable => true, :class => 'index_table') do
    column :name
    column :vintage
    column :varietal
    default_actions rescue nil # test for responds_to? does not work.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I think `table_for(collection)` was the missing logical piece.

Comment: this helped me answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236752/how-do-you-add-a-second-column-of-children-without-duplicating-the-parent-co/35256690#35256690) SO question. Thanks :)

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 Thank  you!