# How do you add a second column of 'children' without duplicating the 'parent' column entry in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

This table, [Raw Table with correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSp29.png), is the result I am looking for, but how do I translate this block of code into whatever Active Admin /app/admin/postal_code.rb index view requires to output the table correctly.

Currently this block is rendered in a partial, /app/views/admin/postalcode/_showtable.html.erb

```
<h1>Postal Code per Region</h1>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Postal Code</th>
</tr>
<% @region.each do |region| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= region.name %></td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <% list = @postalcode.where("region_id=#{region.id}") %>
            <% list.each do |l| %>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">
                    <%= l.postalcode %>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <% end %>
           <% end %>
          </td>
        </table>
</table>
```

But this code, [Active Admin Index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aP5v.png), in /app/admin/postal_code.rb is giving multiple parent column entries, one for each second column child entry.

```
ActiveAdmin.register PostalCode do
menu parent: "Region Settings"
permit_params :postalcode, :region_id


index do
 column :id
 column :region
 column "Postal Code" do |region|
   region.postalcode

end
end
```

In app/models/postal_code.rb

```
class PostalCode < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :region
validates :region_id, presence: true
validates :postalcode, presence: true
# scope :region, -> (name) { }
# PostalCode.all.group_by(&:region_id)
end
```

and in app/models/region.rb

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, presence: true
has_many :postalcodes
# has_many :produces, :through => :produceregionmonths
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can create those individual tables with header of the region name and the corresponding postalcodes inside

```
# app/admin/postal_code.rb

index do
  Region.all.each do |region|
    table_for(PostalCode.where(region_id: region.id), class: 'index_table') do
      column region.name do |postal_code|
        postal_code.postalcode
      end
      actions
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed. You're awesome!!

Comment: Aren't you losing the filters doing so? Would'n it be better to change Region.all.each for collection.each?