# ActiveAdmin default actions for associated resources in table_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many

I'm have an `Album` model with an `has_many` relationship to another `Track` model. Both models have their own dedicated pages and menu entries in ActiveAdmin and I would like to keep it so, since it may be useful to see all tracks instead of all tracks of a specific album.

I would like to add the list of associated tracks in the album's show page. I have stumbled upon `table_for` which works really good but doesn't have an `actions` method to show View, Edit and Delete buttons. I guess I could recreate them but before doing so I would like to check if there's a way to mimick the `actions` method used for the index page?

So for I have the following method in `app/admin/albums.rb`, inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429204/1439489 :

```
show do
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    row :release_date
    row :tags
  end

  panel 'Tracks' do
    index_table_for(album.tracks.order(position: :asc, id: :desc), class: 'index_table') do
      column :id
      column(:name) { |track| auto_link track }
      column :position
      column :duration
      # <- add actions here
    end
  end
end
```

PS : I know I could use partials but the list of attributes to show for all tracks vs. all tracks of an album is not the same; also I'm not sure it would help to display actions as the mentioned answer above uses `default_actions rescue nil` most probably for this exact reason

Answer (score 3):

After some wandering I found a solution, not sure if this is the best way to do so but I thought I'd share :

**lib/active_admin_exts.rb**

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsTable::IndexTableFor
  builder_method :index_table_for
end
```

**config/initializers/active_admin.rb**

```
require 'active_admin_exts'
```

**app/admin/albums.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Album do
  permit_params ...

  index do
    ...
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :release_date
      row :tags
    end

    panel I18n.t('admin.labels.tracks') do
      # use *index_table_for* instead of *table_for*
      index_table_for(album.tracks.order(position: :asc, id: :desc), class: 'index_table') do
        id_column # now available
        column :name
        column :position
        column :duration
        actions # now available
      end
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    ...
  end

end
```

I hope this can help someone trying to achieve the same thing quickly. If this is a bid idea for some reason feel free to tell me and suggest a better way!

**EDIT:** be careful with your actions :

- If you disable the `destroy` action for Album, associated tracks listed in an album's page will hide the Delete action too
- If you disable the `destroy` action for Track, associated tracks listed in an album's page will still show the Delete action

For my use case this is good enough because this is a small project and  destroying is prevented at the object's level, but I've raised an issue with the author to investigate properly : https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5959

Comment: This works great! Thanks for sharing